# Show that if the leading principal minors of a nonsingular $n\times n$ matrix $A$ are all nonzero then the matrix $A$ has $LU$ factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination

I am stucked at this problem:

---

Prove by **induction** that if the **leading principal minors** of an $n\times n$ nonsingular matrix $A$ are all nonzero then the matrix $A$ has $LU$ factorization.

(The $k$-th **leading principal minor** of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is the determinant of its upper-left $k \times k$ sub-matrix)

---

My intuition is that we can perform Gaussian elimination on the matrix $A$ without row interchanges (and so $A$ will have $LU$ factorization) , but I wasn't able to formalize it in the induction.

Thanks for any hint/help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint. Let $A$ be a $k\times k$ matrix whose leading principal minors are nonzero. In block form

$$
A = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\hat{A} & a\\
b^T & a_{kk}\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

It follows that $\hat{A}$ is a $(k-1)\times(k-1)$ matrix whose leading principal minors are all nonzero. Thus, by the induction hypothesis $\hat{A}$ has an LU factorization $\hat{A} = \hat{L}\hat{U}$ with the important property that $\hat{U}$ has nonzero elements on its main diagonal.